# Weirdly disappearing comments

Tags: discussion, comments

Recently I've noticed some of my comments and exchanges under posts end up disappearing without any reason. What is happening? I reckon a moderator might be deleting them, or they are being randomly flagged, but these were neither part of an extended discussion, which typically get removed after a while, nor eligible for any of the common comment flags (such as being unkind, spam, etc).

- Has anyone else experienced this? It would be nice to know at least why they are being so promptly deleted. I understand that sometimes when a comment has been addressed and therefore is no longer relevant, then it can be removed. But other times when it's praising a good answer, or suggesting an edit, or criticising something, it would be nice to not have them deleted, as after all it's mostly via comments that we discuss/communicate here in SE and form a cohesive community. Additionally, commented suggestions might also be useful for other and future readers that might also write questions or answers.

I think it would be helpful not to have comments aggressively removed if they are not part of extended discussions, nor mean-spirited. Moreover it's often difficult to judge if a comment is truly no longer relevant, so maybe, it might be best to simply leave them be.

Answer (score 4):

I might have deleted some of them; especially when cleaning up large comment threads, it happens that I inadvertently delete the one that *was* worth keeping. Other comments might have been deleted because they contain certain keywords like 'thanks' or '+1', causing them to be deleted after a single comment flag by *any* user. There's no official list of those keywords (it varies per site) but you can find more information [in this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238837/295232) and related topics.

It's worth keeping in mind that

> Comments are *temporary* "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

(emphasis mine)

and there are [some guidelines about when and when not to comment](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> #### When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).
>
> #### When shouldn't I comment?
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - **Suggesting corrections** that don't *fundamentally* change the meaning of the post; instead, [make](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/editing) or [suggest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) an edit;
>
> ...
>
> - **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, upvote it and [pay it forward](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer);
>
> ...
>
> - **Secondary discussion** or debating a controversial point; please use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead;